# What is MODULE library type in cmake?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, dlopen

`cmake` [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html) documentation says,

> SHARED libraries are linked dynamically
>   and loaded at runtime. MODULE libraries are plugins that are not
>   linked into other targets but may be loaded dynamically at runtime
>   using dlopen-like functionality.

Practically, I can see both `SHARED` and `MODULE` type targets generate `.so` dynamic libraries on Linux. `.so` libraries are dynamically linked, loaded at runtime and be mapped using `dlopen()`. How do these two types of targets differ?

Answer (score 9):

The `MODULE` ones are intended to be loaded using `dlopen` only. You can't `target_link_libraries()` to the `MODULE` library.

As documentation states, `MODULE` keyword should be used to underline that a library is a plugin of some sort and shouldn't be linked using `-l` flag.

Comment: Which `ELF` flags does `MODULE` correspond to? In other words, which dynamic libraries can't be linked? How does it matter as far as `make` rules are concerned?

Comment: IIRC, it is `-rdynamic`.

Comment: Ah, I've misread your question. The module library doesn't have any symbols exported. That why you can't link to it.